# can't find tlmgr

Tags: installing, linux

I have quite some problems installing TeXlive on Kubuntu. I used the installation file provided by [tug.org](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html) and followed [the quick installation guide](http://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) but skipped those steps

**Interfaces to the installer: text, GUI, batch**

and

**Choosing a download host**

since I worked with

```
./install-tl
```

Afterwards I set my `PATH` and tried

```
tlmgr update --all
```

as well as

```
tlmgr --gui
```

followed by

> couldn't find »tlmgr«, did you mean: ...

(I don't know the English version of this). Then I thought, maybe TeXlive is not installed properly, so I tried

```
latex small2e
```

resulting in:

> warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these
>   directories:
>   /usr/share/texmf/web2c:/usr/share/texmf-texlive/web2c:/usr/local/share/texmf/web2c.
>   This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
>
> kpathsea: Running mktexfmt latex.fmt /usr/bin/mktexfmt: 975: .: Can't
>   open /usr/share/texlive-bin/debianize-fmtutil I can't find the format
>   file `latex.fmt'!

What the heck is going on. I don't have a clue. BTW I am really new to Linux.

Comment: If you want an easy, one-command solution, consider removing everything you've installed so far and using  https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu

Comment: How did you set your $PATH?

Comment: Did you install as root? If so, you probably want something like ``sudo `which tlmgr` ...`` as `tlmgr` will not be on the path for root. (I'm assuming a `bash` shell.)

Comment: @Joseph yes, I installed as root (sudo ./install-tl) as ./install-tl gave me:

    ./install-tl: mkdir(/usr/local/texlive/2014/) failed, goodbye: Keine Berechtigung(no permission)

Comment: @Sigur I simply wrote:
    
    PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH

Comment: @scottkosty thanks, I will try it out. Anyway, what was my mistake?

Comment: I guess that your command to update the PATH is temporarily. When you close the terminal you loose it. Open a new terminal and type `echo $PATH` to see. I pass TeXlive to my PATH using the file `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: @Gabriel I'm guessing Sigur is right and that it's PATH related.

Comment: yes, it is PATH related. @Sigur: I will look for that file.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: However, if the path is set, I get this:

gabriel@pc26:~$ tlmgr update --all
tlmgr: package repository http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
You don't have permission to change the installation in any way,
specifically, the directory /usr/local/texlive/2014/tlpkg/ is not writable.
Please run this program as administrator, or contact your local admin.

Comment: sudo tlmgr update --all does not work. What now?

Comment: `sudo su` and then call `tlmgr`.

Comment: Look at this [highly voted answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/4427), which shows in a very detailed way how to install TeX Live from TUG and live happy without any path problem.

Comment: @egreg I'm not sure `/etc/environment` should be used that way. Is that normal on Ubuntu? I'm not sure I'd want `pam_env` picking up my TL binaries...

Comment: Hey! Thanks everyone for the sound response. I think, I might got it going. tlmgr works as well. I had to use chown and chmod for some issues, but an example file is running with Kile.
Another question: Since I messed up big time with the first installation. How do I install new packages, not listed in tlmgr (like [mcode from mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8015-m-code-latex-package))
Thanks again (in advance)

Comment: @cfr Indeed, my suggestion is to add a file to `/etc/paths.d/`

Comment: @egreg That sounds right. I don't have that setup but use `/etc/profile.d` but I know some setups do.